# Migrating from one SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to another

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, migration, ssis

I just started a new dba job and have been given a new server and told to move everything from the old server to the new one, brand new windows and SQL Server installations. I know I have to transfer user databases, logins, SSIS packages and maintenance plans.

1. Is there anything else I should be aware of to move. Both instances are SQL Server 2008 R2.
2. Is there an easier way to move the maintenance plans other than scripting each one and applying these to the new server?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Restoring the MSDB database from the old server will help with a lot of the jobs, maintenance plans, etc.

Comment: Is there a time of day/week that these databases and the instance will not need to be accessed? In other words, is there an acceptable period of down-time?

Comment: @Surfer513, this is a flexible environment. downtime can be scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx

That link has instructions to move system databases from one instance to another, if you move all databases as is (including user ones, for which you can copy the file, however you will need downtime, or if your databases are on a SAN you can use a SAN snapshotting software), the SQL Server will come up with everything intact.. Keep in mind that if you have a named instaces (NAME1\NAME2) then the NAME2 should be same for the destination instance..

Comment: And btw I have tested this approach for many servers, it is much cleaner than scripting and applying..